# I'm not sure why my for loop doesn't continue incrementing "i"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iterator

I'm having difficulty understanding why my code only runs once. I can click the first square that appears and the class changes, but it seems to stop there. I am trying to be able to click squares and have new ones appear and so on. I am unable to click the second square that is created. I've logged "totalSquares.length" as well as "i". "i" seems to be less than the length of totalSquares so I am unsure why my loop stops. I also have a Codepen link [here](https://codepen.io/Southpaw310/pen/poyBVgG). Thank you in advance. Let me know if you need more clarification.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>Test
        <br>
        Your
        <br>
        Aim
    </h1>

    <p>Score: </p><span id="score">0</span>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="square"></div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
let totalSquares = [];
const squares = document.getElementById("square");
const totalScore = document.getElementById("score");
const heading = document.querySelector("h1");
let score = 0;

totalSquares.push(squares);

for (var i = 0; i < totalSquares.length; i++) {
    totalSquares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        createSquare();
        this.classList.add("clicked");
        score++;
        totalScore.innerHTML = score;
        console.log(totalSquares.length, i);
    });
}

function createSquare() {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("id", "square");
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
    totalSquares.push(div);
}
```

Comment: Your loop only runs once. There is nothing in `createSquare` that tells it to add the event listener to the new square.

Answer (score 1):

[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns only 1 element.

So, you push a single element (`squares`) into an array (`totalSquares`).

So, it looks like the for loop runs `totalSquares.length` times which must be 1.

If you have multiple elements with id `square`, give them class `square` instead & get all elements with [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like this:

```js
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the answers. I received some help and the code below accomplishes what I'm trying to achieve.

```
const squares = document.getElementById("square");
const totalScore = document.getElementById("score");
let score = 0;

function createSquare() {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("id", "square");

    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.add("clicked");
        score++;
        totalScore.innerHTML = score;
        createSquare();
    });
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
}

createSquare();
```

Instead of using a for-loop they suggested I put the eventListener directly in the createSquare function so this places an eventListener directly on the square.